# Can updated row in a TABLE be inserted to VIEW as a new row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a TABLE which is continuously updated, the history info is always overwritten.

I have to create a VIEW consolidating all necessary tables' info.

Is there any method to let the VIEW to keep all history info from TABLE (before table row updated and after)?

I know that VIEW only compute whatever info from TABLE, if there is no way, do I must use materialised view?

Comment: Could you, please, add some data example of what you have in and what you want out ?

Comment: A view is just a stored query, it has no data of its own. The view will always return a result based on the _current_ table data.

Comment: hi jarlh, I understand your meaning. Is there any trigger or function which can handle my request?

Comment: You want a tigger that archives the data in the table into another table.